# Android build error: Unable to load 'javax.xml.bind.jaxbexception

Tags: android-studio, synchronization

I am a beginner in Android. I am not able to resolve this error in Android Studio. Whenever I run my application this error occurs. How do I fix it?

> Error: Unable to load class '`javax.xml.bind.JAXBException`' Possible
> causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync
>   project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>   processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of
>   Gradle requested by the project.
> - In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Answer (score 77):

This is my solution

Update Gradle build tool version in project-level Gradle.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
}
```

And then Android Studio will download and change your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

Sync project, everything is OK.

Comment: This is the right answer

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I had cloned an older project and I was using 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3' and gradle-5.4.1-all.zip earlier with Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 24):

My problem was resolved when I changed the JDK for each of my Android SDKs:

Project Structure -> Platform Settings\SDKs -> Android API xx Platform -> Change "Java SDK" to 1.8

This resolved the problem;

Also change that the Project SDK to 1.8.

[image]
[image]

If the problem is not resolved, [Please try to run IDE under JDK 8](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under).

Comment: As I checked in Android studio (bumble bee version-2021.1.2), JDK location was moved to Gradle Settings. So, one can update JDK version either by going to Project Structure > Click on the Gradle Setting link or following this: File > Settings > Gradle JDK

Answer (score 13):

This might be too late but maybe some one needs to know the reason:

If you updated android studio to v4.2 and this happened, its because it is build in java 11

You have two options:

1. change JDK path manually in: **Project Structure** -> **SDK Location**
2. you should update your gradle setting use these two versions or above them:

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip

I hope i could save some one's time

Answer (score 8):

Also you can Update your gradle version in project level gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.x.x'
```

and fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

install java 8, and set your JDK path with java 8

File- > Project structure. -> SDK location -> JDK Location

for mac os:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your gradle-wrapper.properties distributionUrl value and update with latest version of gradle.

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is the one of the possible solutions, It was worked for me.

In app build file, add the options `javaCompileOptions{ ... }`

```
android {
    …
    defaultConfig {
    …
        //add this options
        javaCompileOptions { 
            annotationProcessorOptions { 
                includeCompileClasspath = true 
            } 
        }
    }
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade the Gradle version then it will fix the problem